# Why does HAproxy not maintain cookie session persistence after a change?

Tags: haproxy

tl;dr I change my configuration to move all of the weight onto a new server (alice), expecting cookie persistence to maintain sessions on the existing server (bob), but it doesn't. All requests after the change go to bob.

My stable backend config is

```
backend tl2010
  server srv_tl2010a ${alice}:8040 check weight 100
  server srv_tl2010b ${bob}:8040 check weight 000
  balance source
  cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
  http-response set-header X-Server %s
```

If I want to perform maintenance on alice, I change the weights to alice=0, bob=100 and reload (SIGUSR2).
What I expect is that new sessions will begin on bob, but the JSESSIONID cookie will stick existing sessions to alice. However, what happens is that immediately after reload, all requests go to bob.

Is my config wrong? Have I misunderstood how session persistence works? Does the act of reloading somehow clear an internal cookie affinity table?

Comment: Do not retitle the question with SOLVED or put a solution in the question. Questions are for questions. If you have a solution put it in the Answer field.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

There were two problems.

1. As well as the cookie command, it's also necessary to set a cookie value on each server, thus server srv_tl2010a ${alice}:8040 check cookie a weight 100
2. My app server (Tomcat jsf) doesn't delete the client JSESSIONID cookie on logout. It simply invalidates it at the server and redirects to a login page which sets a new cookie. Haproxy doesn't notice the cookie has changed and so continues the persistent session.